# Using Lsq-Fit in Julia

Tags: julia, curve-fitting

I am trying to practice fitting with the Lsq-Fit-function in Julia. 
The derivative of a Cauchy-distribution with parameters \gamma and x_0.
Following [this](https://julianlsolvers.github.io/LsqFit.jl/latest/getting_started/) manual I tried

```
f(x, x_0, γ) = -2*(x - x_0)*(π * γ^3 * (1 + ((x - x_0)/γ)^2)^2)^(-1)
x_0 = 3350
γ = 50
xarr = range(3000, length = 5000, stop = 4000)
yarr = [f(x, x_0, γ) for x in xarr]

using LsqFit
# p ≡ [x_0, γ]
model(x, p) = -2*(x - p[1])*(π * (p[2])^3 * (1 + ((x - p[1])/p[2])^2)^2)^(-1)
p0 = [3349, 49]
curve_fit(model, xarr, yarr, p0)
param = fit.param
```

... and it does not work, giving a `MethodError: no method matching -(::StepRangeLen[...]`, leaving me confused.
Can please somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with what you've written:

1. the `model` function is meant to be called with its first argument (`x`) being the full vector of independent variables, not just one value. This is where the error you mention comes from:

   ```
   julia> model(x, p) = -2*(x - p[1])*(π * (p[2])^3 * (1 + ((x - p[1])/p[2])^2)^2)^(-1);
   julia> p0 = [3349, 49];
   julia> model(xarr, p0);
   ERROR: MethodError: no method matching -(::StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}, ::Float64)
   ```

   One way to fix this is to use the dot notation to [broadcast](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1) all operators so that they work elementwise:

   ```
   julia> model(x, p) = -2*(x .- p[1]) ./ (π * (p[2])^3 * (1 .+ ((x .- p[1])/p[2]).^2).^2);
   julia> model(xarr, p0); # => No error
   ```

   but if this is too tedious you can let the [`@.`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Broadcast-and-vectorization-1) macro do the work for you:

   ```
   # just put @. in front of the expression to transform every
   # occurrence of a-b into a.-b (and likewise for all operators)
   # which means to compute the operation elementwise
   julia> model(x, p) = @. -2*(x - p[1])*(π * (p[2])^3 * (1 + ((x - p[1])/p[2])^2)^2)^(-1);
   julia> model(xarr, p0); # => No error
   ```
2. Another issue is that the parameters you're looking for are meant to be floating-point values. But your initial guess `p0` is initialized with integers, which confuses `curve_fit`. There are two ways of fixing this. Either put floating-point values in `p0`:

   ```
   julia> p0 = [3349.0, 49.0]
   2-element Array{Float64,1}:
    3349.0
      49.0
   ```

   or use a [typed array initializer](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Typed-array-initializers-1) to specify explicitly the element type:

   ```
   julia> p0 = Float64[3349, 49]
   2-element Array{Float64,1}:
    3349.0
      49.0
   ```
3. This is not really an error, but I would find it more intuitive to compute `a/b` instead of `a*b^(-1)`. Also, `yarr` can be computed with a simple broadcast using [dot notation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1) instead of a comprehension.

Wrapping all this together:

```
f(x, x_0, γ) = -2*(x - x_0)*(π * γ^3 * (1 + ((x - x_0)/γ)^2)^2)^(-1)
(x_0, γ) = (3350, 50)

xarr = range(3000, length = 5000, stop = 4000);
# use dot-notation to "broadcast" f and map it
# elementwise to elements of xarr
yarr = f.(xarr, x_0, γ);

using LsqFit
model(x, p) = @. -2*(x - p[1]) / (π * (p[2])^3 * (1 + ((x - p[1])/p[2])^2)^2)
p0 = Float64[3300, 10]

fit = curve_fit(model, xarr, yarr, p0)
```

yields:

```
julia> fit.param
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 3349.999986535933  
   49.99999203625603
```

Comment: U R AWESOME! Thank you very much! :D Working through your answer I also noticed that I forgot to initialize "fit" in my first, lets call it "code"-attempt. It works fine now. :-)

Another question arising to me is: How could I write the model-function without the "@." next to the equation sign? I tried replacing *every* operation (+, -, /, *, ^) by its dot-analogon .+, .-, etc. but that doesn't seem to work out?

Comment: What you tried should have worked. It edited my answer to show an example of manual dot-notation for all necessary operators.

Comment: Also note that you can always use `@macroexpand @. a + b` to understand exactly what kind of transformation was performed by `@.` (and this works of course for any macro)